# Sort an array based on variable upon insertion

Tags: c, arrays

I have been writing a small program for a library database of book structures. An array is malloc allocated and initialized with 0's in each indexes ibsn long variable and a menu is prompted allowing choices. Upon adding a book it is placed into the first available position in the array (first position where the `ISBN number is !=0`).
My question is how can I add a book to the array whereby it places it sorted by the isbn number first checking if there is space in array?
Example: Book with ISBN 1234 entered into array; Second book added with ISBN 123 and is placed at first index moving the previous book to the next index.

```
void addbook(book_t* lib, int size)
{
    int i;

    //// Loop through the array until you find an empty element
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        /// Found an empty element
        if ((lib + i)->isbn == 0) {
            //// Ask for and store the book details
            printf("Please enter the book name\n");
            scanf("%s", (lib + i)->name);
            printf("Please enter the book author\n");
            scanf("%s", (lib + i)->author);
            printf("Please enter the book number\n");
            scanf("%ld", &(lib + i)->isbn);
            printf("Please enter the book price\n");
            scanf("%lf", &(lib + i)->price);

            printf("We will now ask you for the release date of the book by day then month then year");

            printf("\nPlease enter release date for this book (dd):"); //user able to change default 
            scanf("%d", &(lib + i)->releaseDate.date);

            printf("\nPlease enter release month for this book (mm):"); //user able to change default 
            scanf("%d", &(lib + i)->releaseDate.month);

            printf("\nPlease enter release year for this book (yyyy):"); //user able to change default 
            scanf("%d", &(lib + i)->releaseDate.year);

            printf("\nDate entered is (%d / %d / %d)", (lib + i)->releaseDate.date, (lib + i)->releaseDate.month, (lib + i)->releaseDate.year); //user able to change default 
                                                                                                                                       /// Set i to size so that the loop finished
            i = size;
        }

        //// If no empty element found and at the last element of the array 
        ///  then library is not found
        else if (i == size - 1)
        {
            printf("The array is full\n");
        }
    }    
}
```

I have employed a similar method when deleting a book whereby if the book searched is found it is moved to the last space in the array and has its variables set to 0.

```
void deleteBook(book_t *lib, int size) {
    int i, j, location = 0;
    long searchISBN;
    int found = 0;

    printf("Enter ISBN to search\n");
    scanf("%ld", &searchISBN);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if ((lib + i)->isbn == searchISBN) {
            found++;
            printf("Book Name %s\n", (lib + i)->name);
            printf("Book Author %s\n", (lib + i)->author);
            printf("Book ISBN %ld\n", (lib + i)->isbn);
            printf("Book Price %lf\n", (lib + i)->price);
            location = i;
            i = size;
        } else
        if (i == size - 1) {
            location++;

        }//add to location and try again
    }
    if (found == 1) {
        for (j = location; j < size; j++) {
            strcpy(lib->name, (lib + j)->name);
            strcpy(lib->author, (lib + j)->author);
            (lib)->isbn = (lib + j)->isbn;
            (lib)->price = (lib + j)->price; //user able to change default 
            (lib)->releaseDate.date = (lib + j)->releaseDate.date;
            (lib)->releaseDate.month = (lib + j)->releaseDate.month;
            (lib)->releaseDate.year = (lib + j)->releaseDate.year;

        }//end swapping of elements

        strcpy(lib->name, "0");
        strcpy(lib->author, "0");
        (lib)->isbn = 0;
        (lib)->price = 0;
        (lib)->releaseDate.date = 0;
        (lib)->releaseDate.month = 0;
        (lib)->releaseDate.year = 0;
    } else {
        printf("not found");
    }    
}//end deleteBook method
```

Comment: `&(lib + i)` looks fishy. Provide a [mcve]!

Comment: Try to separate input/output and business logic.

Comment: @Olaf Can confirm &(lib + i) assigns the variable wheras (lib + i) gives nullptr error. By what do you mean  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example! the entire code is it? EDIT: by the statement I mean on variables other than strings (ints, longs, floats).

Comment: @AakashBarapatre How would I accomplish this with a linked list?

Comment: @AnthonyGordon [Insert in sorted way](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/)

Comment: Is it complete? Does it compile? Can it be run? Btw.: "`//end deleteBook method`" - C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: If you use an array, you will have to make a gap by moving all books to the right of the insertion point. Finding a book by ISBN is easy, though. A linked list lets you insert books faster, but it is hard to search, even if the elements are sorted. A balanced binary tree would probably the best data structure here.

Comment: @MOehm Binary Search Tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `deleteBook` does not work correctly: it copies the fields of all entries after the found one over the first entry in the array.  You should just copy the remaining entries as a block with `memmove()`.  Use `memmove()` as opposed to `memcpy()` because the source and destination memory areas overlap.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void deleteBook(book_t *lib, int size) {
    long searchISBN;
    int found = 0;

    printf("Enter ISBN to search\n");
    if (scanf("%ld", &searchISBN) != 1)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
        if (lib[i].isbn == searchISBN) {
            book_t book = { 0 };  // empty book record
            found++;
            // display book data before erasing it
            printf("Book Name %s\n", lib[i].name);
            printf("Book Author %s\n", lib[i].author);
            printf("Book ISBN %ld\n", lib[i].isbn);
            printf("Book Price %lf\n", lib[i].price);
            // copy the remainder elements one position to the left
            memmove(lib + i, lib + i + 1, sizeof(*lib) * (size - i - 1))
            // reinitialize the last entry
            memcpy(lib + size - 1, &book, sizeof(*lib));
            // rescan the current entry in case of duplicates
            // hence do not increment i
        } else {
            i++;  // test the next entry
        }
    }
    if (found == 0) {
        printf("not found");
    }    
}
```

You can use a similar technique to insert a new entry at the appropriate position in the table:

```
void addbook(book_t *lib, int size) {
    book_t book = { 0 };  // empty book record
    int i, used;

    // Loop through the array and pack empty elements
    for (i = used = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (lib[i].isbn != 0) {
            if (used < i) {
                memcpy(lib + used, lib + i, sizeof(*lib));
            }
            used++;
        }
    }
    // reset unused elements:
    for (i = used; i < size; i++) {
        if (lib[i].isbn != 0) {
            memcpy(lib + i, &book, sizeof(*lib));
        }
    }

    // check if the array is full:
    if (used >= size) {
        printf("The array is full\n");
        return;
    }

    // Ask for and store the book details to local book structure
    printf("Please enter the book name\n");
    if (scanf("%s", book.name) != 1)
        return;
    printf("Please enter the book author\n");
    if (scanf("%s", book.author) != 1)
        return;
    printf("Please enter the book number\n");
    if (scanf("%ld", &book.isbn) != 1)
        return;
    printf("Please enter the book price\n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &book.price) != 1)
        return;

    printf("We will now ask you for the release date of the book by day then month then year");

    printf("\nPlease enter release date for this book (dd):");
    if (scanf("%d", &book.releaseDate.date) != 1)
        return;

    printf("\nPlease enter release month for this book (mm):");
    if (scanf("%d", &book.releaseDate.month) != 1)
        return;

    printf("\nPlease enter release year for this book (yyyy):");
    if (scanf("%d", &book.releaseDate.year) != 1)
        return;

    printf("\nDate entered is (%d / %d / %d)",
           book.releaseDate.date, book.releaseDate.month, book.releaseDate.year);

    //// Loop through the array until you find location to insert book
    for (i = 0; i < used; i++) {
        if (lib[i].isbn > book.isbn)
            break;
    }
    // book should be inserted at position i

    // shift book with larger ISBNs
    memmove(lib + i + 1, lib + i, sizeof(*lib) * (used - i));
    used++;
    // copy book into the array
    memcpy(lib + i, &book, sizeof(*lib));
 }
```

For production code, you would need to handle the `scanf` errors appropriately.

These insertion and deletion methods are not very efficient because on average half the database is copied for every operation. A more efficient implementation would use linked lists to avoid copying the data and make it easier to handle a variable number of books.

Comment: In your example would I be correct in saying that the loop finds the book to be deleted and then:  
1: Moves the element one positon further in array (lib[3]->lib[4])  
2: Sets last element to 0.   
3: i-- so that it starts again until the element gets to the end and is initalized with 0?

Comment: @AnthonyGordon: not exactly, if book is found at position 3, remaining elements are moved one position down in the array: `lib[4]->lib[3]`, `lib[5]->lib[4]`... and the last element must be reset in case it was not already empty.  I removed the patch `i--;` because it is counterintuitive, read the comments above.

Comment: if the book to be deleted is found and deleted would it make sense to then make i the value or size to prevent a further iteration ? @chqrlie

Comment: That's debatable: the insert code does not prevent entering duplicate books with the same ISBN.  Should the delete code delete all books with a given ISBN or just the first?  If just the first, add a `break;` in place of `// rescan the current entry`

Comment: in my case only the first book because in the example I am using there would ideally only be 1 isbn rather than duplicates however I do see now why your approach is better as there is a chance of dubplicate isbns due to human error

Comment: @AnthonyGordon: it is a matter of specification: in a public library, its is common to have multiple copies of the same popular books...